# In Ruby, how to display a true/false column as a check mark?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean

I'm very new to Ruby and Rails so someone please help me with this..

I'm creating  basically a To Do list app, and on my table I have a "Done" column. When I generated the scaffold in rails, I made the column like "done:boolean". So now when you create or edit a task it has a checkbox that you can either check or uncheck for "Done". So on the page where it displays the whole list of tasks, in the "Done" column it states either "True" if it was checked, or "False" if it was unchecked. So my question is, How do I replace that "True" or "False" with a Checked Box or an Unchecked box? Also I would like it to grey out the row when "True". Thanks in advance!

Here's some of my code that I tried:

**Index.html.erb:**
`

```
<h1 id="title">Project List</h1>



  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr id="headers">
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Client</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Hours</th>
        <th>Done</th>
        <th colspan="3"></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody class="col-md-2" id="listItems">
      <% @projects.each do |project| %>
    <tr id="table">
      <td><%= project.title %></td>
      <td><%= project.client %></td>
      <td ><%= project.description %></td>
      <td><%= project.hours %></td>
      <td><%= check_box_tag "project_#{project.id}", "#{project.done}", "#{project.done? ? 'true':'false'", "#{project.done? ? 'true':'false'" %>
      </td>



          <td>
            <span title="Show">
              <%= link_to " #{image_tag('show.png')}".html_safe, project, id:'showButton' %>
            </span>
          </td>


          <td>
            <span title="Edit">
              <%= link_to " #{image_tag('edit.png')}".html_safe, edit_project_path(project), id:'editButton' %>
            </span>
          </td>

          <td>
            <span title="Delete">
              <%= link_to " #{image_tag('destroy.png')}".html_safe, project, id:'destroyButton', method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
            </span>
          </td>

        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <br>

  <%= link_to 'New Project', new_project_path, id:"new" %>
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised that the line `<% if project.done("true") %>` doesn't throw an error.

You'll need to show a check box so use the [`check_box_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-check_box_tag) and from that you can display it being checked or not by testing if the project is done.

```
<%= check_box_tag "project_#{project.id}", "#{project.done}", project.done?, disabled: "#{project.done?}" %>
```

Taking these in order, this code will render a checkbox with:

1. an id and name of project_*id_of_project*; and
2. a value of 0 or 1 depending on whether the project is done or not; and
3. it being checked if the project is done and unchecked if not; and
4. the box disabled if project is done.

The marginally interesting code in this answer is:

```
"#{project.done? ? 'true':'false'"
```

This is an inline if/else. The part `project.done?` will return true or false and then output the part before the colon if true and the part after if false.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The line I had before did throw an error! But I updated my code above to what you have given me, and I get a really long error titled "SyntaxError" when I run it?

Comment: Sorry, untested at the time. I've checked and there were some unclosed brackets and a syntax error which I have now amended.

Comment: No problem, I just appreciate the help! So this definitely works showing the boxes. But they show up as all checked, no matter if its true or false.

Comment: One further correct. The third argument just requires a true/false input, not strings as previously.